# Create a Java Stored Procedure in MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Can I create a java stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2005 like in Oracle or DB2?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You can create a .net stored procedure instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxsa8hkf(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

For general extensibility, you can always call into a .net sproc that calls a web service. Then you can plug whatever system you want on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solving mind simply cannot except "No".  Would it not be possible to write an extended stored procedure dll (in .NET or vanilla C) that calls out to a Java class?  Effectively bridging to Java?

Besides my final statement below - would this not be possible in theory?

"I understand this is akin to travelling around the world in the opposite direction to arrive at my neighbor's house."